# Strapi: Upload files to a specific media library folder using strapi upload api

Tags: strapi

I'm trying to upload files to Strapi's media library through its [upload](https://docs.strapi.io/developer-docs/latest/plugins/upload.html#examples) api.

Right now, all the files are getting uploaded to "API Uploads" folder.

Is there a way to upload the files to folder of my choice?

I couldn't find any details about it in the documentation.

Answer (score 2):

Currently this is not possible, according to the documentation last updated on December 14, 2022: https://docs.strapi.io/developer-docs/latest/plugins/upload.html#endpoints

> Folders are an admin panel feature and are not part of the REST or the GraphQL API. Files uploaded through the REST or GraphQL API are located in the automatically created "API Uploads" folder.

There is a feature request on this, so users can vote: https://feedback.strapi.io/feature-requests/p/support-for-media-folders-in-the-content-api

(In the feature request, there's discussion on how to do it in a hacky way, did not test it myself)

Also, If you have to create many folders (like I had to), you would have to do it manually through the interface, but my solution was to automate it with a script that creates them directly onto the db table.